# Subtract values from line above the current line in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, row, subtraction

I've the following table:

```
| id | Name | Date of Birth | Date of Death | Result |
| 1  | John | 3546565       | 3548987       |        |
| 2  | Mary | 5233654       | 5265458       |        |
| 3  | Lewis| 6546876       | 6548752       |        |
| 4  | Mark | 6546546       | 6767767       |        |
| 5  | Steve| 6546877       | 6548798       |        |
```

And I need to do this for the whole table:

Result = 1, if( current_row(Date of Birth) - row_above_current_row(Date of Death))>X else 0

To make things easier, I guess, I created the same table above but with 2 extra id fields: id_minus_one and id_plus_one

Like this:

```
| id | id_minus_one | id_plus_one |Name | Date_of_Birth | Date_of_Death | Result |
| 1  | 0            | 2           |John | 3546565       | 3548987       |        |
| 2  | 1            | 3           |Mary | 5233654       | 5265458       |        |
| 3  | 2            | 4           |Lewis| 6546876       | 6548752       |        |
| 4  | 3            | 5           |Mark | 6546546       | 6767767       |        |
| 5  | 4            | 6           |Steve| 6546877       | 6548798       |        |
```

So my approach would be something like (in pseudo code):

for id=1, ignore result. (Because there is no row above)

for id=2, Result = 1 if( (Where id=2).Date_of_Birth - (where id_minus_one=id-1).Date_of_Death )>X else 0

for id=3, Result = 1 if( (Where id=3).Date_of_Birth - (where id_minus_one=id-1).Date_of_Death)>X else 0

and so on for the whole table...

Just ignore id_plus_one if there is no need for it, I'll use it later for the same thing. So, if I manage to do this for id_minus_one I'll manage for id_plus_one as they are the same algorithm.

My question is how to pass that pseudo code into SQL code, I can't find a way to relate both ids in just one select.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you describe this, it is just a self join with some logic on the select:

```
select t.*,
       ((t.date_of_birth - tprev.date_of_death) > x) as flag
from t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.id_minus_one = tprev.id
```